# how to add external razor script file to umbraco 7.2.4 in web matrix

Tags: razor, umbraco

i need to add web service to my umbraco web application for that in umbraco 6.1.6 version i use a published web form user control, and it will works.

but it wont works with 7.2.4,because umbraco 7.2.4 version have razor view engine as default.

in macro section they give another options as razor script file to use as a user control.

i try to create a mvc  viewusercontrol application but that also working in web form engine.

please give an idea to connect my webservice to umbraco apploication.

and explain  how to use viewusercontrol with razor script.

Comment: You can change the default engine in Config/umbracoConfig.config file

Comment: thanks you very much. it's great.

that is fine, now my user control works.

if  i create a view in visual studio means, how to get it  in umbraco.

i tried to create a view and partial view in visual studio project of umbraco nuget installed.

after running it i cant see the view page in umbraco developer(macro) section.

please give me a solution.

Actually i need to connect my webservice with umbraco application.

the user entries will send to MSSQL Data Base.

please provide any useful tips.

Comment: Your macro should be placed in Views/MacroPartials. The go to Developer section and right click on Macro and click Create. You should then be able to view your macro in the dropdown list.